# BindingSource filtering - C# WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, binding, datagridview

I'm having some trouble trying to create various filters for my DataGridView.
Basically I have 4 buttons that are 'Today', 'This Week', 'This Month','This year' and 'Show All'.
When I click any of the buttons I would like to be able to only display the rows that are relevant to the button pressed. The data for the date is stored on the following format: "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00" including the dashes and colon.

Using my BindingData how can I correctly filter through the entries with the given format? If you need any code for anything please let me know.

Comment: Why is the date/time data stored as text?  What you want to do would be easy if it was actually binary dates/times but by storing the data incorrectly you make using it difficult.  Is the way the data is stored within your control?  By the way, your title says WPF but then you claim to be using a DataGridView, which is a WinForms control.  What's up with that?

Comment: My mistake about the title, it was late when I sent this, and yeah the way the date and time is stored is beyond my control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CollectionView and CollectionViewSource to filter the data. You can refer to MSDN.
[How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx).

Wish it can help you.

> To group, sort, and filter the data in a DataGrid, you bind it to a CollectionView that supports these functions. You can then work with the data in the CollectionView without affecting the underlying source data. The changes in the collection view are reflected in the DataGrid user interface (UI).
>   The CollectionView class provides grouping and sorting functionality for a data source that implements the IEnumerable interface. The CollectionViewSource class enables you to set the properties of a CollectionView from XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I was looking for, I don't know if it is the best way to do it. (I'm sure there are much better ways, so if there are please let me know I'm wanting to learn here!)

Here is my code snippet showing what I wanted to achieve:

```
private void todayToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = _dataSource.Tables[0].DefaultView;    //have a temp dataview to filter data in
        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        date = DateTime.Today;

        string expression = date.Year.ToString() + "-" + 
            date.Month.ToString() + "-" + date.Day.ToString();



        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("thedate = #{0}#", expression);
        _tableNameBS.DataSource = dv;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = _tableNameBS;
    }
```

_tableNameBS is a BindingSource, so now to remove the filter in another function all I need to call is '_tableNameBS.RemoveFilter' and it is reverted to the original.